# JavaScript expand/collapse not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to configure some JavaScript for on my website from here:

(http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Wkat3/)

I was testing it but I can't seem to get it to work. Here's what I put in but it doesn't seem to want collapse and expand like in the result.

```
<html>
<title>
</title>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('li:not(".q")').hide();

$('li.q').click(
function(){
    $('li:not(".q")').slideUp();
    $(this).nextUntil('.q').slideDown();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li class="q">Question One</li>
    <li>first answer to question one</li>
    <li>second answer to question one</li>
    <li class="q">Question two</li>
    <li>first answer to question two</li>
    <li>second answer to question two</li>
    <li class="q">Question three</li>
    <li>first answer to question three</li>
    <li>second answer to question three</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help!
A friend helped me install jQuery so I am not sure if that's the problem or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any error in your browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your js with jQuery(document).ready

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('li:not(".q")').hide();

$('li.q').click(
function(){
    $('li:not(".q")').slideUp();
    $(this).nextUntil('.q').slideDown();
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! just copied it from the site as never used JavaScript before :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) for the current item

```
$('li:not(".q")').hide();

$('li.q').click(function(){
    var $li = $(this).nextUntil('.q');
    $('li:not(".q"):visible').not($li).slideUp();
    $li.slideToggle();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hacg6/)